# table Valued Function Query Optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, query-optimization

Working on table Valued Function Query. Which is eating about 70% of the whole query execution time.
Need some help in fine tuning it.

```
INSERT INTO #XMLTAB
SELECT ID,CAST(tab.tabxml as xml).value('(/Root/Element)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM tab 
WHERE TabScore= 36
```

Ref :

- `#XMLTAB` is Temp table.
- `Tab` is table name in database.
- `tabxml` Column holds xml file
- `tabscore` is another column.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you post query execution plan ?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using SQL Server XML data type.
Do you know you can index it?

Try with this:

```
CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX PXML_tab_tabxml
ON tab (tabxml)

CREATE XML INDEX IXML_tab_tabxml
ON tab (tabxml)
USING XML INDEX PXML_tab_tabxml FOR PATH;
```

First statement will shred your xml to internal structure (index rows) and enable SQL Server more effectively query such disassembled XML. This is known as a PRIMARY XML INDEX.

However, if you are querying your XML from some table using a value() method, consider running the second statement which will further speed up such operations. This is known as a SECONDARY XML INDEX and can be of [three different types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx).

Be aware that creating such XML indexes on large tables where XML already exists can take time.

Comment: tabxml is ntext, which holds xml data

Comment: Well, in that case you can't do much. First solution is fixing your schema and altering ntext to xml, and you SHOULD do it if you can. The other possibility is adding calculated persisted field to that table, something like `tabxmlxml = CAST(tab.tabxml as xml) PERSISTED`, indexing that, and querying that instead of ntext. There are really no other options to speed this up.